# Monotouch.Dialog Customizing cells

Tags: iphone, .net, uitableview, xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

I wanna customize cells in MonoTouch.Dialog.

For example make custom background in `BoolElement` and make custom image for this small bool thing that can be on or off, sorry forgot the name, or make custom disclosure indicator image in `StringElement`.

Is there simple way to do this without making own custom elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In some cases you'll need to create *custom* `Element`-derived types to *customize* cells. In other cases you will be able to add some *custom* code inside your application. FWIW I think it's cleaner to create your own everytime.

You can find a lot of examples in the **Sample** application that is available on [github](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) along with MonoTouch.Dialog (that includes having a custom background and totally owner-drawn elements).

There are also several questions (with answers) about common MonoTouch.Dialog customizations  here on stackoverflow. Click on the **[monotouch.dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/monotouch.dialog)** tag and read them.

If you get stuck on a particular customization then don't hesitate to ask for help.